# Why is it printing 4 instead of 3 numbers for first part?

Tags: python, list, printing

```
l = open(filename)
string = l.read()
subsetA, subsetB = string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]
print(subsetA)
print(subsetB)
```

It keeps printing this:

```
9 17 4 8
11 18 13
```

I am expecting to get:

```
9 17 4
8 11 18 13
```

The textfile:

```
9 17 4 8 11 18 13
```

Any help? Thank you! I still don't understand why I am doing wrong this part:

```
subsetA, subsetB = string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]
```

Comment: Why *do* you expect to see only `9 17 4` for the first half of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting a string of length 18 in two:

```
>>> text = '9 17 4 8 11 18 13\n'
>>> len(text) // 2
9
>>> text[:9]
'9 17 4 8 '
>>> text[9:]
'11 18 13\n'
```

so the division makes *perfect sense*.

Even without the newline at the end, making it length 17, would still work:

```
>>> text = '9 17 4 8 11 18 13'
>>> len(text)
17
>>> len(text) // 2
8
>>> text[:8]
'9 17 4 8'
>>> text[8:]
' 11 18 13'
```

You are not dividing the string in half based on the number of groups of digits here, you are splitting purely on the number of string characters.

If you wanted to do that, split the line first:

```
>>> parts = text.split()
>>> parts
['9', '17', '4', '8', '11', '18', '13']
>>> parts[:len(parts)//2]
['9', '17', '4']
>>> parts[len(parts)//2:]
['8', '11', '18', '13']
```

Comment: If i was to do that. subsetA = len(string[:8]) then I will get just plain 8.

Comment: That's because that is the **length** of the sliced string, which is, surprise, 8 characters long.

Comment: Thank you for the third solution.